# Behavior MutableCopy when object is Nil

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, immutability, mutable

(I cant find this on the Net)

All code is within one object. In the .h file I define a NSMutableArray. And I alloc it 
in an init.

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        definitionArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self initialLoadDefinitionData];

        if([definitionArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
           NSLog(@"Array is Mutable");
        } else {
           NSLog(@"Array is Not Mutable");
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

I want to initialize based on NSUserDefaults values, so I call another function from the 
init. This called initialLoadDefinitionData:theCollection is very basic.

```
-(void)loadDefinitionData{
    definitionArray=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SOMEKEY"] mutableCopy];
}
```

I have added the isKindOfClass in the init function just for debug purposes. The fun part
in this is that this IF statement returns MUTABLE when data could be fetched from the 
NSUserDefaults. However if the @"SOMEKEY" was not available, the objectForKey returns a
nil and the definitionArray suddenly is IMMUTABLE. Even if the mutableCopy is specified.

So my conclusion is that if a objectForKey cannot find an object, the return value is
NOT MUTABLE. Is this conclusion correct?
Or can't MutableCopy not address an object as mutable with it is Nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your conclusion is not right. If the `objectForKey` returns `nil` then you 're sending a `mutableCopy` message to `nil` which returns of course `nil` (every message sent to `nil` in ObjC returns `nil`) and that's why you' re seeing the `else` part. (The `Array is Not Mutable` message is misleading since you do not even have an `NSArray` instance at this point).

Comment: I understand what you say, and also agree with that. However when I include an addObject statement right after loading, the value is not added. And the type remains NonMutable. So this probably means that after every objectForKey which returns nothing, I have to alloc the array again.

Comment: @Vincent If `objectForKey:` doesn't find a key it evaluates to `nil`. This means that you have: `definitionArray = nil`. It's not that you have an empty array, you just set your ivar to `nil` instead. I hope that this makes sense...